# jquery avoid multiple requests preventDefault

Tags: jquery, multiple-instances, preventdefault

I need a way to prevent multiple submits:

```
$("#myDiv").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('open');

    // submit the form    
    $('#myDiv #myInput').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        /* ajax call here */
        console.log('clicked');
    });

});
```

So if when I click `#myDiv` is sending X times click to the child function.

eg. if you click 3 times `#myDiv` and then click `#myInput` will send 3 times the form, and if you press again will send 6.

Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: This is why this happens this way: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html

Comment: Are you trying to submit the form when you click #myDiv? Shouldn't you just trigger .submit() on the form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you are binding click event handler multiple times for `$('#myDiv #myInput')`..

You should either move the `$('#myDiv #myInput').click(function(e){` outside the click handler of `$("#myDiv").click(function(e) {` or use `.one(`. Note that in both cases the behavior is different.

Also use should use [event.stopPropagation();](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) to stop event bubbling.

Try below code as per your requirement. The below items 1. and 2. works differently, so please understand the code and implement as per your requirement.

1. Moving #myInput click event outside

   ```
   $("#myDiv").click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   e.stopPropagation();
   console.log('open');
   });

   // submit the form    
   $('#myDiv #myInput').click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();
      /* ajax call here */
      console.log('clicked');
    });
   ```
2. Please note that the click handler for #myInput will be executed once.

   ```
   $("#myDiv").click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();
      console.log('open');

      // submit the form    
      $('#myDiv #myInput').one(function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
       e.stopPropagation();
       /* ajax call here */
       console.log('clicked');
      });
   });
   ```